When importing third-party module in standalone component ,test cases failing jest
importing third-party module in standalone component
Standalone component test cases are not running it's breaking from the imports
Application running without any compilation error but in jest test case only failing . It can't find out the npm package

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
